# PHP won't echo environment variables despite them appearing in var_dump

Tags: php, apache, debian

I have a Debian 12 server running Apache2 (virtual hosts) + PHP 8.2.

I am struggling to get PHP to read environment variables, and am testing using this code:

```
<?php
   $scriptUrl = $_ENV['SCRIPT_NAME'];
   echo "$scriptUrl";
?>
```

Strangely, nothing is printed on the page.

I have tried this with several other environment variables, such as `SCRIPT_URL`. I have also tried using the `getenv('SCRIPT_URL')` function to no avail.

I ran  `var_dump($_SERVER);` which returned a large number of variables, including `SCRIPT_NAME` which was correct, however no PHP I try seems to be able to access any variables.

I imagine this is related to my Apache / virtual host / PHP configuration.

Comment: Can you share you virtual host configuration file and php.ini where `expose_php` is given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why do you expect `SCRIPT_NAME` to be set as an environment variable? You usually find that in the `$_SERVER` superglobal not in `$_ENV`. `$scriptUrl = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];` should give you the expected results.
2. Not all environment variables are necessarily populated to the superglobal. `var_dump($_ENV)` might show different (or no) results compared to `var_dump(getenv());`. See [variables order](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) for details.
3. To see what's available try:

```php
var_dump($_ENV);

var_dump(getenv());

var_dump($_SERVER);
```

Comment: Thank you. Discerning `$_SERVER` and  `$_ENV` completely eluded me. Documentation on this seems rather sparse. Furthermore, what would cause two servers to have different (_server) environment variables eludes me.

Comment: @Samg381 There's nothing special in environment variables, any script or user can create them. Two different servers having the same exact variables, that would be a notable event.

Comment: Thank you! How would I tell which script created an environment variable like `SCRIPT_NAME`? Presumably that script must be running with each HTTP request, since it is updated to show the current URL, no?